# Stop buffering of HTML5 video after video element removed in iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, video, html5-video

I am using `video` tag to play video in my HTML5 application. I have a scenario where I have to remove video element from the page and will create it later, (hiding and showing will not work for me).

Now, the problem is to stop the buffering of video after `video` element has been removed. I have tried this code:

```
 $('video').attr('src','');
 $('video').remove();
```

It is working fine in firefox and chrome. But not working in iPad Safari. In iPad, video will buffer till end, so If I will stop the video 5-6 times. 5-6 buffering has been started and it hangs my application.
I have created a fiddle to test out:
http://jsfiddle.net/7maoc9k3/4/

Please help me to stop buffering of video before `video` element has been removed.